# history.push() is updating urls but not re-rendering components

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-dom, browser-history

I'm facing a problem with react-router-dom. I'm trying to use `history.push` for navigating after an action conducted. but the problem is `createBrowserHistory from history` is updating the urls but components are not re-rendering. I've used every solution from https://stackoverflow.com/. But it's still not working as expected.

*However I found a reason behind it. As my components are wrapped with `connect` function `connect` is preventing the re-render. And there was a solution too, wrap the `connect` function with `withRouter`. I tried it too. But it's not working.*

**Here is My App.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import history from "../history"
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import LogIn from "./LogIn";
import StreamCreate from "./streams/StreamCreate";
import StreamDelete from "./streams/StreamDelete";
import StreamEdit from "./streams/StreamEdit";
import StreamList from "./streams/StreamList";
import StreamShow from "./streams/StreamShow";
import Profile from "./streams/Profile";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Router history={history}>
          <div>
            <Navbar />
            <Route path="/" exact component={StreamList} />
            <Route path="/streams/new" exact component={StreamCreate} />
            <Route path="/streams/delete" exact component={StreamDelete} />
            <Route path="/streams/edit" exact component={StreamEdit} />
            <Route path="/streams/show" exact component={StreamShow} />
            <Route path="/login" exact component={LogIn} />
            <Route path="/my-streams" exact component={Profile} />
          </div>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Here is the history.js**

```js
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export default createBrowserHistory();
```

**Action Creator:**

```js
import Streams from "../API/Streams";
import history from "../history";

export const createStreams = (formData) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  const { userId } = getState().auth;
  const response = await Streams.post("/streams", { ...formData, userId });
  dispatch({ type: "CREATE_STREAM", payload: response.data });
  history.push("/")
};
```

Comment: Try to wrap your components like:

`
<Router history={history}>
          <Switch>
         {/* your routes*/}
</Switch>
</Router>
`

Comment: This might be trivial, but did you try using `render` instead of `component` for your routes?